# Paragraph text inside LI tag

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am wrapping paragraph inside LI tag and even if i set specific width for Li(ex: 200px), text is not wrapped and displaying in single line and spanning outside of LI. Any suggestions to wrap text to fit the width?

sample text

```
 <UL>
 <LI>
 <p>hi hello welcome</p>
 </LI>
 </UL>
```

i tried to add word-wrap: break-word; that seem to fix width issue but not doing proper word wrap

it is displaying as

```
hi hello wel
come
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/PUCnE/): your reduced test case appears to have reduced away the problem. Try providing a complete test case that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The problem hidden under CSS not [markup](http://jsfiddle.net/XZSWD/) you provided us.

Comment: css is not very complex , just i am setting width of Li to 200px,using inline styling for that.

Comment: @Bumble — Doing that does not create the problem you describe.

Comment: @Bumble, your markup with css you said works good: http://jsfiddle.net/XZSWD/1/

Comment: Thanks for your replies , i will check the whole markup and post it here

Comment: just created jsFiddle for this problem.http://jsfiddle.net/GvG9t/

Answer (score 1):

word-wrap: break-word; is a CSS3 Rule, If you rely on this then i'm pretty confident it's going to have issues in older browsers, From what I have read I would try applying the width to the paragraph tag instead of the li or do both add the width to the li and p tags, also try adding display: block to the p tags.